# Как в производном объекте запустить конструктор родительского?

Tags: наследование, javascript

Как сделать чтобы в производном объекте запускался конструктор родительского и можно было
в div с классом style добавлять еще что-нибудь(например изображения)

```
function First(){
    this.obj = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(this.obj);
    this.obj.className = "style";

}
function Second(){

}

Second.prototype = First;
one = new Second();
```

Comment: http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance#vyzov-roditelskih-metodov

Answer (score 1):

Прочитав [эту](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance#nasledovanie-na-klassah-funkciya-extend)  и [эту](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance#vyzov-roditelskih-metodov) ссылки можно придти к упрощенному решению для вашего случая
и

```
function First(a){
   this.attr1="parent initialized with "+a;

}
function Second(a){
    First.prototype.constructor.apply(this,[a])
    this.attr2="child initialized with "+a;
}

Second.prototype = First.prototype;
var one = new Second(2);
console.log(one);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/dT5Ba/